# If my friend has GTA 5 for 360 and I have one can I invite them to my game online?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-online, xbox-one

My friend and I want to play GTA 5 together online, but I have an Xbox one and she has an Xbox 360. Can I join or invite them to my game so we can play together?

Answer (score 1):

Due to differences in hardware and gaming architecture it's not possible to cross platform game on GTA V.

Comment: Although this answer is correct, it was probably downvoted because it does not provide explanation, sources, additional information, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Xbox One has more hardware, different hardware, and more up to date hardware than the Xbox 360, you cannot play games together.